# What are the factors that affects select query's performance which include multiple joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a huge database and my task is to improve its performance to avoid the timeout issues and minimize the select query duration's. 
Which all areas do i need to concentrate to improve the performance of Stored Procedures effectively? 
How does sites like facebook store huge amount of data and still doesn't lack on performance? 
What can be done to improve the performance of SPs?

Comment: 1. First and fore most thing is following **SET BASED APPROACH** in your code 2. Adding relevant `Index`

Comment: Performance tuning is a huge topic. There's quite a lot of free session recordings available for example in sqlpass.org or sqlbits.com

Comment: Apart from Tuning Advisor is there any better way to know where to apply indexes?

Comment: How many records are in your huge database?

Comment: Is this a production environment where records are streaming in and you're also running queries to report from it? A separate, dimensional data warehouse could be the next step if this is the case and the volumes are large.

Comment: Yes its production environment and the database keeps increasing day after day and so the performance comes down gradually. There are 30,000 records inserted every day into a table, in fact those are video details that gets stored into metadata table and video detail table. Note: Video's details are stored in DB and not actual videos .

Comment: As a rule of thumb, every column with foreign key is a good candidate for a simple index. Think what happens when You delete row in the referenced table. Or when You filter by the referenced key. Database tuning advisor tends to make big complex indexes that only few queries can fully use. It is a good start, but for performance critical or huge tables it is better to build indexes on Your own.

Comment: Which?  MySQL?  Or SQL-Server?

Answer (score 0):

Ninety percent of slow queries can be fixed by adding/rebuilding indexes.  Make sure that you have indexes on all the tables involved, and that your [join clause criteria match those index keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311040/does-the-column-order-in-the-where-clause-matter-for-index-selection).

Note that adding indexes can have its own performance cost, however, especially when you insert records.  But it's usually worth it.

Comment: Currently I'm not adding indexes for the reason is to tune the procedures as much as possible to improve the performance. And the last on list would be to create indexes because i don't want the database size to go high and obviously the insert query performance gets affected.

Comment: @JohnVM Doing query optimization without indexes really does not make much sense.

Comment: Rebuilding indexes is not needed for MySQL.  I don't know about Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to improve Stored Procedure performance in SQL Server,  would recommend below 3 things:

1. Add 'SET NOCOUNT ON' in the SP --- It can provide a significant performance   boost, because network traffic is greatly reduced.
2. Try to use columns in the where conditions which are mainly indexed.
3. Verify the execution plan and if you see multiple parallelism occurring, try to use OPTION(MAXDOP N) where N you can set as per the requirement.

Comment: What do you mean with option 3? Are you encouraging increasing or decreasing parallelism? "As per the requirement" is really vague.

Answer (score 0):

the question is

> factors that affect multiple joins

There are many things that affect negatively but the usual suspects are below.

1. Lack of Index on the joined columns
2. Inefficient join orders for `OUTER JOIN`
3. Use of Subquery
4. Modification of search arguments or join column (e.g.`A.intColumn+1 = B.intColumn`

Clauses like `ORDER BY` will also impact performance in general.

Answer (score 0):

(MySQL-centric answer)

`JOINs` are performed by tackling one table at a time.  The optimizer picks which one it thinks is best to start with.  Here are some criteria:

- The table with the most filtering (`WHERE ...`) will probably be picked first.
- If two tables look about the same, the smaller table will probably be picked first.

Something like that occurs when picking the 'next' table to use.

MySQL almost never uses more than one index per table in a `SELECT` (assuming there are no subqueries or `UNIONs`).  A Composite `INDEX` is often useful.  Sometimes a "covering" index is warranted.

See my [*index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Stored Routines do not help performance much -- unless you are accessing the server over a WAN.  In that case, a SP cuts down on the number of roundtrips, thereby improving latency.

30K inserts per day?  That is trivial.  Where is there performance issue?  On big `SELECTs`?  Is this a Data Warehouse application?  Do you have Summary Tables?  *They* are the big performance boost.

Millions of rows?  Or Billions?

Normalized?  Over-normalized?  (Do not normalize 'continuous' values such as FLOAT, DATE, etc.)

That's a lot of hand-waving.  If you want some real advice, let's see a slow query.

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, it all comes down to indexing. This is best illustrated by using an example. Suppose you have two tables T1 and T2 and you want to join them. Each table only has 1000 rows in it. Without indexing, the query execution plan will take the cross product of the two tables and then iterate through sequentially filtering out the results that don't match the where condition. For simplicity, lets just assume only one row matches the filter condition.

T1 X T2 = 1000 * 1000 = 1,000,000 
Without indexing, filtering will require 1 million steps.

However, with indexing, only 20 steps will be required. Log2(n)